# Visting direct links after a redirection cookie exists

Tags: php, cookies, redirect

I have this code for my wordpress site

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['iwashere']) || ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes")){
setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+20000,'howtobuygoldoffshore.com');
header("Location: http://www.howtobuygoldoffshore.com/sitemap"); 
exit;
}
```

it works perfectly well and redirects new users based on cookies .

Now if someone wants to visit a link directly ie:http://howtobuygoldoffshore.com/process-payment  they cant open it since it redirects them to a landing page due to to the cookie redirection

I wish to use it both the ways. A new user should also be able to visit direct links properly without seeing the landing page if he is going directly to the links such as http://howtobuygoldoffshore.com/process-payment

Can this be possible?

Comment: What exactly is "a new user"?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

You could check if index.php (or any other landings page) is given or something similar, and do or don't redirect.

Comment: how can I check this - any specific line which can be written and tried. I am new to these types of issues.

Comment: Add this to your script: `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and post the output of a landingspage and your index.